# Get last 5 years of dates in a JSON variable - loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to know how I can retrieve the last 5 years and the the last 10 years of dates from a JSON Variable which is in the following format.

```
var dates = 

"[{\"Date\":\"1996-05-31T00:00:00\"},{"Date\":\"1996-06-30T00:00:00\"},{\"Date\":\"1996-07-31T00:00:00\"},{\"Date\":\"1996-08-31T00:00:00\"},{"Date\":\"1996-09-30T00:00:00\"},{\"Date\":\"1996-10-31T00:00:00\"} ...
{\"Date\":\"2013-08-31T00:00:00\"},{"Date\":\"2013-09-30T00:00:00\"},{\"Date\":\"2013-10-31T00:00:00\"}]"
```

note ... is where I left off all the variables in between because of space.

This is what I have so far:

```
var data = JSON.parse(dates);

var d1 = [] d2 = [], d3 [];

var today = new Date();today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var last5Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() -5)).getTime();
var last10Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 10)).getTime();

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var s = data[i].Date.split('T')[0];
  var t = [new Date(s).getTime()];
  d1.push(t);  // all dates
  if (t[0] > last5Years) {
   d2.push(t); //push last 5years dates to d2
  }
 else if (t[0] > last10Years) { 
   d3.push(t); //push last 10 years dates to d3
 }
}
```

The d2 seems to work but the d3 for some reason is not correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want just every single day of the year for 5 years?  Or are you wanting times?

Comment: `getTime()` of 5 years ago, and 10 years ago and compare to your dates....seems pretty simple.

Comment: do you want to segregate the dates from the data array into 2 categories > 5 and > 10

Comment: @SolomonClosson  yes I need 3 arrays - all (d1), last 5 (d2) years, last 10 (d3) years in the same format as d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Get **`today's date`** as below

```
var today = new Date();  //returns dateTime
today.setHours(0,0,0,0); //reset time to zero to get only the date part
```

2) To get back to *5 years back*, get and set it.

```
var last5Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 5)).getTime();
```

3) Now to get *back to 10 years, again reduce today's year by **5(not 10)*** and set it.

```
var last10Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 5)).getTime();
```

4) As you already parse the date in json, just add the following conditions

```
var s = data[i].Date.split('T')[0];
    var t = [new Date(s).getTime()];
    d1.push(t);  //push all dates to d1
    if (t < last5Years) { 
        d2.push(t); //push last 5years dates to d2
    }
    else if (t < last10Years) { 
        d3.push(t); //push last 10 years dates to d3
    }
```

Finally you're code will be

```
var data = JSON.parse(dates);
var d1 = [], d2 = [], d3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i<data.length;i++) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    //Get time of last 5 years
    var last5Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 5)).getTime();
    //Get time of last 10 years
    var last10Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 5)).getTime();
    var s = data[i].Date.split('T')[0];
    var t = [new Date(s).getTime()];
    d1.push(t);  //push all dates to d1
    if (t < last5Years) { 
        d2.push(t); //push last 5years dates to d2
    }
    else if (t < last10Years) { 
        d3.push(t); //push last 10 years dates to d3
    }
}
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need, I'm getting this error though, TypeError: today.setFullYear(...).getTime is not a function
var last5Years = today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear + 5).getTime();

Comment: @uknowit2 Sorry it was a typo error. change it as `var last5Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 5)).getTime();`

Comment: ok I think we are very close. my d1 series and the d2 series have exactly the same data. console.log(last5Years) = 1543389063839 and my last date series is 1380499200000, first being 833500800000, therefore the t < last5Years brings in everything.

Comment: @uknowit2  `1543389063839`  seeing this I can assure that `last5Years ` is taking both date and time.  So we need to reset the time for `today`.  let me give it.

Comment: @uknowit2 Just add `today.setHours(0,0,0,0);` next to `var today = new Date();`.  Now the problem will be fixed.  Let me if it works.

Comment: @uknowit2 can you make a fiddle?  So I can also try without suggesting ideas?

Comment: I edited the question to show the latest update thanks to your help. The d1 and d2 seem correct but not the d3, any ideas?

Comment: @uknowit2 the reason is `today` is already reduced to 5 years.  But we are again reducing to 10 years.  Totally variable `last10Years` is 15 years back. So change `var last10Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 10)).getTime();` to var last10Years = new Date(today.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() - 5)).getTime(); Hope you understand,